# /dev/sda2 unexpected inconsistency run fsck manually

Tags: kali-linux, disk, fsck

I'm getting the following error:

```
/dev/sda2 unexpected inconsistency run fsck manually
```

The boot process stops here and there is no way to input any commands.

See this error message:
[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

According to the image, there is possibly a physical I/O error due to a bad disk state.

You need to face the inevitable and replace the disk ASAP.

What I mean is to try to use `gddrescue` package which contains the GNU `ddrescue` program and use it according to its manual. Just plug your disk into some other server or computer and use it to rescue any possible remaining *good* data.

(I wish you that the most important data (if you have any in there) can be salvaged.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to put this, but from the look of it (and guessing from the outcome, because I can't see how you've indexed your disk) it sounds like the partition that houses your entire core system has encountered a severe hardware error ('`input/output error`' almost always indicates that the kernel tried to read or write something to a hardware driver and got a result it doesn't know what to do with).

Most proper Linux distributions use an initramfs that (among other things) allows for a very rudimentary shell to be started so that fsck can indeed be run manually. I can only speculate as to why Kali -- [whose recommended use case is neither for general desktop use or for people who are still inexperienced with linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) -- doesn't.

Your best bet at this point would be booting from a live USB stick and running diagnostics on `/dev/sda2` in the hope that something can be salvaged.